# How to access the CKEDITOR namespace or object in angular 9?

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using Ckeditor4-angular (3.1.1) in Angular 9. It is the npm package listed in ckeditor documentation for angular implementation. I followed the basic steps and am able to see the ckeditor with the standard toolbar options. Added 'CKEditorModule' in app.module.ts and added the below ckeditor tag in the component.html.

```
              <form>
                <ckeditor #myEditor name="myEditor" editorUrl='https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.19.1/full/ckeditor.js'
                           id="myEditor" readOnly="true" data="allBills" [(ngModel)] ="allBills">
                </ckeditor>
              </form>
```

Now, I want to access the CKEDITOR class and make changes in my component.ts
I declared -

```
var CKEDITOR: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'xyz',
  templateUrl: './xyz.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./xyz.component.css']
})
```

And tried to get the instance using the following line.

```
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['myEditor'];
```

I get an error - 'ERROR TypeError: CKEDITOR is undefined'

I tried

```
@ViewChild('myEditor') editorTag: any;
```

and tried to access instance of ckeditor using - `this.editortag.instance` But I'm not able to change the config options using this method. My final goal is to get the print plugin in the ckeditor toolbar. 'Print' plugin is available in the full package of Ckeditor. Since the Ckeditor4 angular component by defaults loads the standard-all CDN, I changed the editor url to full version as seen above.  And I added
`[config]="{ toolbar: [{name:'document', items:['Print']}] }"`
in the ckeditor tag. Upon adding this I don't see anything in the toolbar.

I need help to access the CKEDITOR object in component.ts to manually change the config options and add the 'Print' plugin or if there's any other solution or something I'm doing wrong please let me know.

Comment: The `[config]` binding works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-urcax5?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @skink Did you use the same code which I showed and got the output? Or did you add anything else in it?

Comment: @skink I resolved the issue by loading the CKeditor4 CDN before the Ckeditor component. I'm having a new issue. My data is html with different text formatting. When using [config] binding with only print option, html styles are not being applied. But they work when I mention all the toolbar items like Bold, Italic, table etc. in [config] binding. But that also adds those buttons to the toolbar which I don't want. I only want print button to be displayed and also see all html styles and formatting.